# Deferred Deep Link Integration without third party SDK and framework integration

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I want to implement deferred deep linking in my iOS app as a means of tracking referrals and campaigns to increase user-base.
we'll generate a URL that has certain params in it. When the link is shared to the user and they click it it, We want it to take them to my app's page in the App Store. Then if they install my app, upon app launch, want to read the params from the link/URL.

Have implemented all the things like enabling associated domain, generating profiles, hosting AASA file on domain, integrated all the delegate methods in app-delegate of app.
But some or the other reason not able to read the params in url/link.

The tutorials i referred to implement:
[Universal-Links-iOS](https://abhimuralidharan.medium.com/universal-links-in-ios-79c4ee038272)

There are lots of old pages out there that recommend solutions like tracking the user's IP address, putting the params into the clipboard, or somehow obtaining it from a cookie in a web view. But somehow i don't feel they are the only way out.

Also don't want to use any third party SDK's like Branch.io and etc.

Please StackOverflow community help me out. What i'm lacking upon to connect the loose ends.

Comment: I used the same link but after lots of debugging, I found an issue in the AASA file. After fixing that now my dynamic link is working fine. Your referred tutorial is perfect way to integrate

Comment: Abhishek Patel can u suggest how the link is created, as for me still not getting callbacks in the  func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {}

Comment: You might receive at onOpenURL(perform:) , check your URL Schemes (BundleId) & Associtate domain name .  If this is not helping then you have to check dynamic link setup

Comment: How should one create dynamic links? Is there any specific format?

Comment: There's no Apple approved way to do *deferred* deep linking on iOS. That's why the third parties exist to get around the limitation using hacks and heuristics. It would be a lot of work to implement yourself in a reliable way.